# malloc for string pointers: how it can be disastrous?

Tags: c++, string, malloc

In [this Informit C++ guide](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=34), I read this:

> Using `malloc()` to create a non–POD object causes undefined behavior:
>
> ```
> //disastrous!
> std::string *pstr =(std::string*)malloc(sizeof(std::string));
> ```

I didn't understand 2 points here :

- Pointers are PODs. Then why it is called non-POD here? (Maybe I have to understand POD better.)
- How can this be so disastrous? (I guess I have to understand string Internals for this.)

Please explain!

Comment: You are not "creating a pointer" in this case. You are "creating" a `std::string` object. `std::string` is not POD.

Comment: The answer is in the link your mentioned: "new and delete automatically construct and destroy objects. malloc() and free(), on the other hand, merely allocate and deallocate raw memory from the heap."

Comment: If you add to that `malloc()` an in-place constructor invocation (look up `new()` for that), it'll be OK. But then you'll need to call the destructor manually and `free()` the memory, not `delete` it.

Answer (score 5):

> pointers are PODs then why here it is called non-POD

It's not talking about the pointer, but the `std::string`.

It's disastruous because `malloc` doesn't call the constructor, so you'll have `pstr` a `std::string` pointer that points to a `std::string` that wasn't properly constructed. The memory was allocated but it wasn't initialized properly, because of the missing constructor call.

The correct way is

```
std::string *pstr = new std::string;
```

The clean way is to just have a variable in automatic storage:

```
std::string str;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are *allocating a standard string*, not *allocating a pointer to a standard string*.  Note that you are passing `sizeof(std::string)` to malloc; that is how much memory you are getting back...note the size of the object is bigger than the size of a pointer.  If you were only allocating a pointer, you'd expect the size passed in to be `sizeof(std::string*)`.

The pointer you receive back is how you keep track of the result of the allocation, but that pointer isn't living on the heap.  Here it's just being stored in an ordinary variable.  Had you allocated a pointer instead, then your variable to keep track of it would need to be a pointer-to-a-pointer.

Anyway, if you wanted to, you could legally *allocate a pointer to a standard string* like this:

```
std::string str;
std::string** ptr_to_pstr = (std::string**)malloc(sizeof(std::string*);
*ptr_to_pstr = &str;
```

Why you would want to is not entirely clear.  But neither is it clear why you'd use malloc in C++.  :)